# Kucoin Java SDK error KC-API-KEY not exists

Tags: java, kucoin

Following their guide in usage [here](https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-java-sdk) I couldn't get started.

The code:

```
    KucoinClientBuilder builder = new KucoinClientBuilder()
            .withApiKeyVersion(2)
            .withBaseUrl("https://openapi-sandbox.kucoin.com")
            .withApiKey("MyKey", "MySecret", "MyPass");
    KucoinRestClient kucoinRestClient = builder.buildRestClient();

    KucoinPrivateWSClient kucoinPrivateWSClient;

    try {
        kucoinPrivateWSClient = builder.buildPrivateWSClient();
        KucoinPublicWSClient kucoinPublicWSClient = builder.buildPublicWSClient();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`builder.buildPrivateWSClient()` throws an exception with this message:

```
KucoinApiException{code='400003', message='KC-API-KEY not exists'}
```

I copied the Api Key and Secret and pass from the [api page](https://www.kucoin.com/account/api)

[image]

What am I missing here? Why the KC-API-KEY does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sandbox" account is different than the original account.
Its domain is different and you need to register in the sandbox version of the website [here](http://sandbox.kucoin.com)